# How to get decimal degree data from a shapefile in QGIS

Tags: arcgis, qgis

I am trying to extract decimal degrees data from a shapefile using the QGIS software but no luck. I am using the field calculator method where i create a new double field then select Geometry then $x and $y but am still getting data in this format 247152.338941123. Have set the CRS layer to WGS84 but no luck. Please if you know what am doing wrong, help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the values returned it seems that your layer is stored as a projected coordinate system. Try saving the layer as a **geographic** coordinate system (EPSG:4326) and it should work.